# unzipping list into two separate lists in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function called unzip that takes a list and evaluates to a list of two lists that have alternating elements of the original list.

so far this is what i have:

```
(define (unzip lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (...
```

this is how it should work:

(unzip '(1 a 2 b 3 c)) should evaluate to ((1 2 3) (a b c))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is on the wrong track, sorry. (Think about what the result should be if given an empty input.) Similar to my answer to your last question, here's a skeleton solution:

```
(define (unzip l)
  (if (null? l) ???
      (let ([next (unzip ???)])
        (list (cons ??? ???) ???))))
```

Fill in the `???`s appropriately. (Yes, my solution is tested and works for both odd and even inputs.)

Comment: `next` is not a function. It's a variable defined inside the `let`. Now, think about what it should logically do. (I've changed the brackets to be square, more in line with Racket's style. Hopefully this should make things even more obvious.)

Comment: Yes, `next` is indeed `(unzip (cdr l))`. Now, you should think about how you would assemble the new result given the old result. Try this: think about what the result is, for an empty input. Then, for a single-element input. Then for 2 elements. And so on. You'll quickly get an idea for what you need to do at each step.

Comment: The `(cons (car l) ???)` part is correct. The `(cdr l)` part is not. Can you figure out why not? (Also, hint: at least one subexpression will involve the `next` variable. Otherwise, there's no point for me to define it in the first place.)

Comment: Congrats! If you want to compare your answer to mine, look at this: https://gist.github.com/871a0abf0aa6a020f52b